# which one is a better choice for android webservice developing,Rest or Soap?why?

Tags: android, web-services

I am going to develop a app which uses webservice, i don not know clearly what are differents between soap and rest for android developing,which one is better?why
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rest is to prefer. Soap is for large project and are not suitable for mobile applications. 
But have you thought about JSON? I've made projects with JSON with great success.

Take a look at this: 
http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/

Answer (score 1):

The difference has nothing to do with Android: REST is simpler.  If a client can make an HTTP request, they can deal with a REST service.

SOAP services require an XML envelope to contain the message.  The client has to marshal data into the XML format, encode the request, and only then POST it to the service for processing.